# Why does Google Play Store say that Adobe Air is incompatible with the Huawei U8510 phone?

Tags: huawei, adobe-air, arm-processors, hardware-requirements

I looked at the [publisher's system requirements](http://www.adobe.com/uk/products/air/tech-specs.html) for Adobe Air.

I compared that list to [Huawei's device specs](http://www.huaweidevice.com/uk/productFeatures.do?pinfoId=3103&directoryId=6001&treeId=3713&tab=0), but Huawei's list doesn't mention if the device has

> ARMv7 processor with vector FPU, minimum 550MHz, OpenGL ES 2.0, H.264
>   and AAC HW decoders

How can I figure out why the store says the device is incompatible, and whether that conclusion is correct? I would prefer an answer that didn't involve installing the SDK, but if it requires reading and comparing device.prop and the APK, please provide a link to suitable directions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your device doesn't have an Armv7 processor.

It has an Armv6. You can confirm this by attempting to download apps like Temple Run & Firefox from the market - these all need Armv7 processors. You can also install [Device Info](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jphilli85.deviceinfo) to check it yourself, it gives you detailed information.

Also, according to [GSM Arena](http://www.gsmarena.com/huawei_u8510_ideos_x3-3840.php) your processor is clocked to 600Mhz - the same as most Armv6 devices.

Comment: Thanks. Perhaps I am not the only one who finds ARM version numbering hard to find, and then hard to understand :) Of course it is a budget phone, so I don't expect it to run everything, even though Flash Media apps such as BBC iPlayer would be nice. (You are right: Firefox and Temple Run won't install either.)

Comment: @dcorking Most budget phones come with Armv6 processors as, well, they are cheaper! They also require less RAM... There *was* a flash player for Armv6 devices, you will have to Google for it. Not sure about Air though, and the flash didn't run that well...

Comment: @LiamW most new phones sport an ARMv7 today. http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1596800

Comment: @ce4 True, however some still don't...

Comment: @ce4 This phone is still on general sale. It seems to be a 2012 revision of the U8510 marked U8510-1. (Apparently Adobe's Flash player was pulled from the Play store, leaving Air the only obvious option to play DRM compressed video and audio.)

Comment: Over at XDA the flashplayer app can still be downloaded: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1850772